How to make app screen sharing with Android 14?
In MyApplication, I have already used MediaProjection to make the device screen sharing successfully. From https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/app-screen-sharing?hl=en I know I can share a single app window. My questions are:

Does that mean I can use MyApplication to capture AnotherApp's window and cast it to MyApplication?
If the answer is YES, how to do this exactly? (I don't know how to let user choose which screen to share... I didn't find detailed API description in Android Document.)

My steps to get screen sharing are:

ask user's runtime permission

createScreenCaptureIntent()


use the intent to get mediaProjection
getMediaProjection(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, intent)


create virtual display, I use MediaRecorder's surface as virtual display surface
mediaProjection!!.createVirtualDisplay("VirtualScreen",
                       width, height, dpi,
                       DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mediaRecorder!!.surface,
                       null, null)




With MediaProjection, it's not allowed to directly capture an app's window and throw it into the window of another application. That is made intentionally so that bad applications do not spy on good ones, in addition to not breaking through the Android security and users privacy.
